# Wi-Fi randomly disconnects and asks for password

Tags: networking, wireless, 22.04

My Wi-Fi keeps on disconnecting and asking for the password.
I have made sure that the password is saved, but it still keeps doing it.
Below is the output of the `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` command.

```
06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 [8086:2723] (rev 1a)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200NGW [8086:0084]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!
FYI: It works fine if I dual-boot Windows and on other devices.

Comment: If the WiFi is dropping of course it asks for password when it comes back.

Comment: Hey, it is not a Wi-Fi issue, as I said, it works fine if I dual-boot Windows and on other devices. It is Ubuntu in particular.

Comment: sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager

Comment: Thank you so much, that seems to have resolved it. Could you post that as an actual answer so I can mark it as solved? Thanks. @petep

Comment: Nevermind, that did not fix it.